# Large sinkhole getting larger

Tags: sinkhole

I live in central Florida.  I had a sinkhole 10' long by 2' wide by 6' deep. 3 years later it is now 25'L x 8'W x 2'D. Growing at this rate, from previous postings, it seems to be an underground stream. I'm very reluctant to try to fill it because who knows when it will stop, and it seems to be a lost cause. Can a professional stop something like this?

Comment: Voted to close -- the only real answer here is "consult a professional" because they can tell you what they can and cannot do.

Comment: Consult a soils engineer who can consult a geology expert. Florida friends tell me it's much bigger underground and you'll need a string of dump trucks and a county budget.

Answer (score 1):

I think the quick lime can react with water and then will prevent the sinkhole from extending